# How can I Use WSDL Webservies in IOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, soap-client, wsdl2objc

I am trying to use WSDL Webservice in my IOS application. I have google it for several days and I am not able to fetch data from the server. 
My Service URL is similar to http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL.

I want to know how can I create soapMessage and soap Action. Whether the below code is must to create WSDL parsing

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope \n"
    "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"
    "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n" 
    "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
    "soap:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
    "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"
    "<soap:Body> \n"
                       "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                       "<Celsius>23</Celsius>\n"
                       "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
    "</soap:Body> \n"
                       "</soap:Envelope>
```

If there is any sample please share me

For android we have used Ksoap2 and fetch the data successfully

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

http://www.jdb-software.com/index.php/9-latest-news/11-soap-in-ios

regards

Johan

Comment: Hai, Most of the links are show 404 error and currency conversion code is very simple. The basic thing I need to know is how to create a SoapMessage for Http request